# Arcade IIF function, return field name plus string

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I am pretty new to programming so I don't really understand how I can do this.

Basically I have data with field that are 0, I wanted to display "No Data" when the field is 0, and when it is not 0, for example 1977, I wanted to display "The building was built on 1977.

This is what I have right now

IIF($feature["YEAR_BUILT"]=="0", "No Data", $feature["YEAR_BUILT"])

However, when I want to add the string " The building was built on" like so,

IIF($feature["YEAR_BUILT"]=="0", "No Data", "The building was built on $feature["YEAR_BUILT"].")

The error message said unexpected token. How should i work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this line:

```
IIF($feature["YEAR_BUILT"]=="0", "No Data", "The building was built on $feature["YEAR_BUILT"].")
```

needs to be:

```
IIF($feature["YEAR_BUILT"]=="0", "No Data", "The building was built on " + $feature["YEAR_BUILT"] + ".")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried the code you provide, but for 0 values, it returned as "The building was built on 0." However, other values works perfectly!

Comment: Then your year_built field is actually a numeric field (not unreasonable for a year) so simply remove the quotes around the zero as currently you are testing if it is equal to a string that happens to hold a zero character.